# Unable to link 'animated button' to php file for uploading a file

Tags: php, html

Okay. So basically I'm trying to upload a file through an upload button in a form . 
My code was working fine until I decided to make my upload button a little 'stylish'. Silly Me.

The $_POST query in my php file is not able to identify that animated button. I have tried to link the class name of that animated button in the POST query but nothing seems to be working.

Here's my html form code with my animated button in it:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<label for="file" style=" font-weight:normal;  font-family: Tahoma;   font-size:20px; "></br></br></br>Upload the list of Teaching Assistants here:</label>
<input  type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
    <!--<input type ="submit"  name="submit" value="Upload" />  This button is working perfectly-->

<br />


    <div  class="button-wrapper" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     <a href="upload_file.php"  class="a-btn">
    <span class="a-btn-text">Upload </span> 
        <span class="a-btn-slide-text">FILE!</span>
    <span class="a-btn-icon-right"><span></span></span>
                </a>

            </div>
    </form>
```

Here's my php code:

```
<?php
session_start();

include "connect1.php";


if ($_POST["submit"])
{
if ($_SESSION["name"])
{
    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $type = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
    $size = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $error = $_FILES["file"]["error"];

    if($error > 0)
    {
        echo "Error!".$error;
    }
    else
    {
        if (file_exists("upload/".$name))
        {
            echo $name." already exists";
        }
        else
        {
            $location = "upload/".$name;
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location);
            $user = $_SESSION["name"];
            $sqlcode = mysql_query("INSERT INTO upload (id,user,location) VALUES ('','$user','$location')");
            echo "<a href='$location'>Click here to view the file </a>";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Please Sign In";
}
}
else
{
echo "<a href='index.php'>";
}
```

Getting this error:

Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\xampp\htdocs\smartalloc\upload_file.php on line 7
Basically - He's asking me to provide a type for my $_POST query but nothing is working.

Any help would be really appreciated. :)

Comment: Unfortunately we arn't mind readers, code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the form to submit and send all the information from your inputs, you need the submit button to be a proper form element that is capable of submitting the form.

You can't just make a fancy link or `<span>` or `<div>` or whatever and just expect the form to know that you want that element to submit the form for you.  What you have to do is keep your submit button:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Upload the list of Teaching Assistants here:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And instead, style it using CSS.  There are lots of options, and you can make a really nice looking button.  See any of these tutorials as an example (or just Google *"submit button CSS"* for more).

http://speckyboy.com/2009/05/27/22-css-button-styling-tutorials-and-techniques/

Secondly, I see that you have tried this:

```
<div  class="button-wrapper" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

That is not valid HTML.  You cannot make any element (in this case a div) into a form.  The `method` and `enctype` attributes can only go on a `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are now using a link instead of a button so there is no POST event taking place.

Trying changing your animated button back to an actual button and styling it with CSS.